# Im not able to write any async function in a class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

```
constructor(backend){

        this.backend = backend;
        let ProviderClass = require(`./provider/${backend}.js`);
        this.setProvider(backend);
        this.provider = (async () => {
            let provider = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                (new ProviderClass(acl)).then(function(provider){
                    return resolve(provider);
                }).catch(function(err){
                    return reject(err);
                });
            });
            return provider;
        });
    }
```

This is giving below error:

```
    this.provider = (async () => {
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I tried with writing async function, but even that is throwing an error stating that whatever i give function-name it is treating it as identifier and not as a function.

Help me with this!

Comment: Can anyone help??

Comment: Did you make sure your version of node is new enough? Include the node version in your post.

Comment: There's no reason for `async` or `await` in your function.  Just return the promise from a regular function because that's all an `async` function returns anyway.

Comment: asynchronous operations inside a `constructor` seems a bit odd to me.